# Entity Framework code-first, Null entries being written to database

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Refer to my code example below where I'm trying to implement a code-first connection to a SQLite database. I am working in .NET 4.8 (not Core). All the column names and database table names are correct. `Id` is the unique primary key in all database tables. The database tables for `Derived_B` and `Derived_A` are distinct. Both have `Id`, `Name` and `Information` columns.

The `Widgets` table has a foreign key relationship to the `Id` in `Derived_B`, via an additional integer column not listed in the above code. I can programmatically create instances of  `Derived_A`, `Derived_B` and `Widgets`, add them to the `Example_DataContext`, and call `SaveChanges()`.

Afterwards, valid entries for `Derived_A` and `Widgets` are written to the database. The new entries in the `Widgets` table have valid foreign-key relationship back to the `Derived_B` table.

Here is where I am stuck -- while appearing to have the correct number of entries, the new entries in `Derived_B` are empty apart from the index column. The logged output from the datacontext indicates that just the ID column is being written to `Derived_B`. Why? What am I missing?

I would expect that the new rows in `Derived_B` would have valid data.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace entityExample
{

    class Baseclass
    {
        [Column(name:"Name")]
        public string name { get; internal set; }
        
        [Column(name: "Information")]
        public string information { get; internal set; }
    }

    [Table("Derived_A")]
    class Derived_A : Baseclass
    {
        [Column(name: "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Derived_A() {}
    }

    [Table("Derived_B")]
    class Derived_B : Derived_A
    {
        public Derived_B() {}

        public List<Widget> widgets { get; internal set; }
    }

    [Table("Widgets"]
    class Widget
    {
        [Column(name: "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(name: "Name")]
        public string name { get; internal set; }

        [Column(name: "Description")]
        public string description { get; internal set; }
    }


    class Example_DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Derived_A> Derived_As {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Derived_B> Derived_Bs { get; set;}
        public DbSet<Widget> Widgets { get; set;}
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        
            modelBuilder.Entity<Derived_A>().ToTable("Derived_A");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Derived_B>().ToTable("Derived_B");
        }
    }
}
```

My code for saving to database:

```
foreach (Baseclass item in items)
{
    if (item is Derived_B derivedB)
    {
        dbContext.Derived_Bs.Add(derivedB);
    }
    if (item is Derived_A derivedA)
    {
        dbContext.Derived_As.Add(derivedA);
    }
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Well - **show us the code** that creates those new rows and saves them ! Remember - we can neither see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to show all relevant code bits!

Comment: Thanks, added code that saves data to DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each subclass to contain the shared columns you need to tell EF explicitly to use Table-per-Concrete configuration, otherwise it will likely just assume that since B inherits from A, and A inherits from Base, then either Base or "A" will contain the name and other columns, and B's Id will link back to A to associate the two.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Baseclass>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();
modelBuilder.Entity<Derived_A>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();
```

I honestly would avoid deep inheritance, and pretty much any inheritance when it comes to EF Entities. Code like:

```
if (item is Derived_B derivedB)
{
    dbContext.Derived_Bs.Add(derivedB);
}
if (item is Derived_A derivedA)
{
    dbContext.Derived_As.Add(derivedA);
}
```

is a notable red flag for maintainability.